# It is possible to store multiple data in arrays

Tags: java

Is it possible for the array I have created to hold multiple data? 
For example when a user adds a game I want to display the total score for multiple games, however with the below code, my array only contains the last input data.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assingment2
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        String text;
        String gameName;
        int scores;
        int timePlayed;
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        text = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your game achivements (Game name:score:time played) E.g. Minecraft:14:2332");

        while (i < 100){

            text = sc.nextLine();

            if (text.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Nothing was entered. Please try again");
                break; 
            }

            if(text.equals("quit")){
                break;
            }

            System.out.println (text); 
            i++;

            String [] splitText = text.split(":");

            if (splitText.length !=3){
                System.out.println("Error please try again");
                break;
            }

            gameName=splitText[0];
            scores=Integer.parseInt(splitText[1]);
            timePlayed=Integer.parseInt(splitText[2]);

            System.out.println("Game: "+splitText[0]+", Score= "+splitText[1]+", Time Played= "+splitText[2]);               
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: @CubeJockey I was simply putting it in the right tag, so other people with Java (not Javascript) experience could edit it correctly.

Comment: @A.hussain will you add some sample imput and output, specially what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @ShvetChakra

Please enter your name
Ali

Please enter your game achivements (Game name:score:time played) 
E.g. Minecraft:14:2332

minecraft:12:432

Game: minecraft, Score= 12, Time Played= 432

GTA:324:2124

Game: GTA, Score= 324, Time Played= 2124


What I want to achieve is, adding the scores, and time played together to get the total time played and total score for all the games the user inputs, however I'm not sure on how to allow a array to store multiple data

Comment: just make an array of gameName, scores and time played and then either just keeping adding into that array and sum it at the end or just summing your values at every iteration.

Comment: Probably the best way is to create a `Game` object that has the variables `name`, `time`, `score`. Then you can store the `Game` in an array and access the variables by `arrayOfGames[0].getName();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Have 2 classes called `Player` and `Game`. The `Game` class can be something like the following:

```
public class Game {
      String name;
      int score;
      int timePlayed;
}
```

and the `Player` class can be something like the following:

```
public class Player {
      String playerName;
      ArrayList<Game> gamesPlayed;
}
```

Then, in the main program, you can add code to iterate through the players, add game data, manipulate game data etc.